# Number of iterations in compound loop

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am comparing rows to each other just once, so the inner loop decreases in size each iteration:

```
let num_1 = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < 500; j++){
       num_1++;
    }
}

console.log(num_1); // 500*500 = 250,000


let num_2 = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    for(let j = i+1; j < 500; j++){
        num_2++;
    }
}

console.log(num_2); // x*y = 124,750
```

it looks like x and y are 250 and 499, but not sure why, can anyone explain?

Comment: nah I meant potential components of 124,750

Comment: it should just be 499+498+497+496+...+1, if you sum the endings, they sum to 500, and then there are 249 pairs I guess

Comment: The expected sum is (start + end) * count / 2 as per [Gauss](https://study.com/academy/lesson/finding-the-sum-of-consecutive-numbers.html)

Comment: Because of that `i+1`, you're really counting 498 + 497 + ... + 1.  Which is 499 * 250. I guess the formula for k rows against each other, no repeats, is `(k**2-k)/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't want over-analyze this one, but looks like:

```
499+498+497+496+...+1
```

there are `249` pairs of `500` (499+1, 498+2, 497+3, ...etc)

and then one odd 250 in the very middle, so the number is:

```
249*500 + 250
```

which doesn't seem to follow Gauss' rule of:

```
(start + end) * count / 2
```

if someone could reconcile that, that'd be cool

Comment: There are 250 pairs of 499 (499+0, 498+1, 497+2, …), which matches Gauss' rule just fine